# Set of keys from a map

Tags: f#, hashtable

I have a map X and I'm trying to get a set of the keys satisfying a certain condition, something like this:

```
Map.Keys X
|> Set.filter (fun x -> ...)
```

...but I cannot find the way to get the keys from F#'s Map collection.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Convert your [map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340432.aspx) to sequence of tuples `(key,value)` first and then map it to a sequence of just keys:

```
map |> Map.toSeq |> Seq.map fst
```

FSI sample:

```
>Map.ofList[(1,"a");(2,"b")] |> Map.toSeq |> Seq.map fst;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [1; 2]
```

Or alternatively, as ordering of keys likely does not matter you may use more eager method returning the `list` of all keys. It is also not hard to make it into extension method `keys` of `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Map` module:

```
module Map =
    let keys (m: Map<'Key, 'T>) =
        Map.fold (fun keys key _ -> key::keys) [] m
```

Comment: The result should be a set not a list

Comment: @GuillaumeMassé: The author apparently had trouble just with "...the way to get the keys from F#'s Map collection", so the answer addressed this specific matter.

Comment: @ympostor it depends on (a)your definition of efficiency and (b)if the need for high performance exist in the given context. Nevertheless, the original problem in whole is more effectively addressed by F# 4.0 `Map.filter`. Also for my suggested approach filtering may be fused into `fold`, like in `let filterKeys<'K,'T when 'K: comparison> (p: ('K -> bool)) (m: Map<'K,'T>) =
        m |> Map.fold (fun ks k _ -> if (p k) then k::ks else ks) []`

Answer (score 3):

In F# 6.0, `Map` collection has now a [`Keys` property](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-fsharpmap-2.html#Keys).

---

**OLD ANSWER**:

Most readable (and probably most efficient, due to not needing previous conversions to `Seq` or mapping) answer:

```
let Keys(map: Map<'K,'V>) =
    seq {
        for KeyValue(key,value) in map do
            yield key
    } |> Set.ofSeq
```

Answer (score 0):

For a set of keys you could just do:

```
let keys<'k, 'v when 'k : comparison> (map : Map<'k, 'v>) =
    Map.fold (fun s k _ -> Set.add k s) Set.empty map
```