# Optimized version of except for Map

Tags: dictionary, optimization, f#

I've written a generic `except` function for `Map`s that, given a source map and an other map, returns only the items of the source map without corresponding keys in the other map.

```
module MapExt =
    let getKeys<'k,'v when 'k : comparison> : Map<'k,'v> -> 'k[] = 
        Map.toArray >> Array.map fst
    let except<'k,'v when 'k : comparison>(other:Map<'k,'v>) (source:Map<'k,'v>)  : ('k * 'v)[] =
        source |> getKeys
        |> Array.except (other |> getKeys)
        |> Array.map(fun k -> (k, source.[k]))
```

Now, I've seen in the second part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19744800/11323942), that an optimized version of the map's keys is obtained via a `Map.fold`.

Therefore, can I do a similar optimization of my original `MapExt` module in the following way?

```
module MapExtOpt =
    let getKeys<'k,'v when 'k : comparison> (m : Map<'k,'v>) : 'k list = 
        Map.fold (fun keys key _ -> key::keys) [] m
    let except<'k,'v when 'k : comparison> 
        (other : Map<'k,'v>) (source : Map<'k,'v>)  : ('k * 'v) list =
        source
        |> Map.fold (fun s k v -> 
            if (other.ContainsKey k) then 
                s 
            else 
                (k,v) :: s
        ) []
```

Or am I reinventing some already existing (and optimized) functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in function, but this is a simpler way of doing what you are trying to do. It only goes over the 'to be removed' map once, so its much more efficient.

```
let except toRemove source = 
    Map.fold (fun m k _ -> if Map.containsKey k m then Map.remove k m else m) source toRemove
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally,
thanks to Loïc Denuzière for his comment on Slack:

> The `if` is not necessary: if `m` doesn't contain `k`, `Map.remove k m` just returns `m` anyway

I think I can also apply a double [eta reduction](https://www.lambda-bound.com/book/lambdacalc/node21.html) by considering that it makes sense to speak about the keys to remove (not about a map whose values are ignored), so I would simply redefine it as

```
let except<'k,'v when 'k : comparison> = List.foldBack Map.remove<'k,'v>
```